# XSD complexType with element AND simpleContent

Tags: xsd, attributes, complextype

Working with XML 1.1 in Oxygen XML Editor version 23.1.
Originally I wandted to make an xsd schema that can have a complexType-element with a child-element, an extension and a bunch of attributes. A first possible solution I was able to get here but figured out it didn't fit to my problem, because the child-element itself consists of several elements and attributes which makes the original approach invalid, causing the error message: "The content type of a derived type and that of its base must both be mixed or both be element-only. Type 'complexTypeContent' is mixed, but its base type is not".

To my problem itself: The aim is for the child-element `random` to only be used when the attribute `until` has the value 'random'. So in the end a XML-file like this should be valid:

```
<instruction>
   <type repeat='1' until='random'><random start='1' end='6'/>Dice Roll</type>
</instruction>
```

Instead - if the attribute `until` has not the value "random" - the element random must not be allowed. So something like this should be forbidden:

```
<instruction>
   <type repeat='1' until='2'><random start='1' end='6'/>Dice Roll</type>
</instruction>
```

With help from here I was able to modify my xsd-scheme to something like this. But as already stated, it doesn't compile without an error message:

```
<xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="instruction" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="type">
                            <xs:alternative test="@until = 'random'" type="complexTypeContent"/>
                            <xs:alternative type="simpleTypeContent"/>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>  

    <xs:complexType name="complexTypeContent" mixed="true">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="simpleTypeContent">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="random" type="random" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="random">
        <xs:attribute name="start">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer"/>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="end">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer"/>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:assert test="@start le @end"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="simpleTypeContent" mixed="true">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="type2">
                <xs:attribute name="until">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:union memberTypes="type2 annotation xs:integer until"/>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:attribute>
                <xs:attribute name="condition">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:union memberTypes="type2 annotation extended"/>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:attribute>
                <xs:attribute name="repeat" type='xs:integer'/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="type2">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Dice Roll"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Wait"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Repeat"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Double Roll"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Instruction"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="until">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="end"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="random"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Instruction"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="annotation">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="rolltwice"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="halfcount"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="doublecount"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="roll-"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="roll+"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="numberChange"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="NoNumberChange"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="extended">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="noRolling"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="noEven"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="noUneven"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="stopped"/>
        </xs:restriction> 
    </xs:simpleType>
```

The error messages I had now all imply that this solution is invalid because of the not mixed content of `simpleTypeContent` or because it has simpleContent which cannot be derived from the complex content of `complexTypeContent`. So, how do I get it working? I cannot figure out any working solution for the problem I am facing.

Comment: Check your favourite XSD 1.1 tutorial on type alternatives. I would think that for instance http://www.datypic.com/books/defxmlschema/ would help you a lot if you are new to XSD 1.1 and need a lighter read than the spec and more precise information than most introductory web articles on such topics provide.

Comment: From all the examples I have seen there is no hint that actually helps me solving this. Only way I saw is to make the element "random" the new parent-element to all attributes and redicect all content to it which is not working when the element should only be optional and attributes and concent should be bound to the element "type".
Is there no way to combine the element "type" with its simpleContent together with a child-element "random" at all???
If there is, I am seriously lost here.

Comment: In your conditional type test you use the expression `test="@until = 'random'"`, meaning you want to check the value of the `until` attribute for the value `random`. I don't see that value in any of the enumeration/list/union types you use in the schema.

Comment: My fault - i forgot to copy that exact line. Have edited the example now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, XSD (not even 1.1) doesn't offer a way to restrict the mixed content text to some simple type, so the only way, if you really need that single element together with a certain list of values seems to be an assertion; that means, unfortunately, you need to duplicate the values you also want for an attribute.

So some (slightly adapted, see my comment about the `@until = 'random' check) sample schema would be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">
    
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="instruction" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="type">
                                <xs:alternative test="@until = 'random'" type="complexTypeContent"/>
                                <xs:alternative type="simpleTypeContent"/>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>  
    
    <xs:complexType name="complexTypeContent" mixed="true">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="simpleTypeContent">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="random" type="random" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    
    <xs:complexType name="random">
        <xs:attribute name="start">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer"/>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="end">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer"/>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:assert test="@start le @end"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    
    <xs:complexType name="simpleTypeContent" mixed="true">
        <xs:attribute name="until">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:union memberTypes="type2 annotation xs:integer until"/>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="condition">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:union memberTypes="type2 annotation extended"/>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="repeat" type='xs:integer'/>
        <xs:assert test=". = ('Dice Roll', 'Wait', 'Repeat', 'Double Roll', 'Instruction')"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="type2">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Dice Roll"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Wait"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Repeat"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Double Roll"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Instruction"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    
    <xs:simpleType name="until">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="end"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="random"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    
    <xs:simpleType name="annotation">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="rolltwice"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="halfcount"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="doublecount"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="roll-"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="roll+"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="numberChange"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="NoNumberChange"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    
    <xs:simpleType name="extended">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="noRolling"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="noEven"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="noUneven"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="stopped"/>
        </xs:restriction> 
    </xs:simpleType>    
</xs:schema>
```

and that then makes the first `instruction` in below sample (also slightly adapted as there was a spelling difference between the schema and the sample (`Dice roll` vs. `Dice Roll`) in your snippets) valid while the second is invalid:

```
<root>
    <instruction>
        <type repeat='1' until='random'><random start='1' end='6'/>Dice Roll</type>
    </instruction>
    <instruction>
        <type repeat='1' until='2'><random start='1' end='6'/>Dice Roll</type>
    </instruction>
</root>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. OxygenXML-Editor only throws an error message:
"The content type of a derived type and that of its base must both be mixed or both be element-only. Type 'complexTypeContent' is mixed, but its base type is not."

Doesn't make sense to me since both are declared mixeed though. Any solution?

Comment: Works for me as posted in oxygen 24 with Xerces and Saxon EE.

Comment: cannot confirm. Am stuck with this error in Oxygen 23.1 :(
He is not allowing me to use the sequence for including the element random.

Comment: Do you get the error with oXygen 23.1 with the samples from my answer? Or with some attempt to adapt them to your needs/other types? Which version of Saxon EE does oXygen 23.1 have for validation scenarios with XSD 1.1? Have you tried both Saxon and Xerces?

Comment: yes, I get it even if I copy it literally line by line. He always is against the sequence-element.
Not entirely sure about Saxon but I think it is supposed to be version 9.9.1.8.
I am unfamiliar with Xerces. How do I use that?

Comment: Xerces is usually the default XML validating parser in oXygen. You can select in the options whether Xerces or Saxon is the default. When you configure a validation scenario you can also select between the default or Saxon or Xerces I think. Anyway, I have posted what I can contribute to that question as an answer, let's see whether someone else shows up to tell you more. You can of course try to install an evaluation copy of oXygen 24.1 to see whether it makes the difference or ask their support whether they know any restrictions with 23.1 compared to 24.1 and XSD 1.1.

Comment: Okay, let's see what I will figure out.
Anyway - thank you for your atempt. I will also try to adapt your solution. Maybe like this I get the answer.

Comment: By the way: Now after finding out about Saxon and Xerces I was able to make some checking. Saxon is displaying another error-message:
"The type Q{}complexTypeContent has complex content so it cannot be derived by extension from the complex type Q{}simpleTypeContent which has simple content"

Comment: That doesn't make sense with the schema sample I posted as both types have `mixed="true"`. I also now tried the samples with https://www.softwarebytes.org/xmlvalidation/ and the schema is used fine, the instance is not valid at line 9, as expected/wanted.

Comment: I don't know why the original example is failing. But when I try to adapt it to my overall program I am using a subtype "type2" which basically is a String and has only specific values allowed. Since this is a simpleType as well, maybe it is connected to these weird error messages?

Comment: I used a subtype relationship as it seemed to apply to the (reduced) sample I used to demonstrate the use of xs:alternative. But the alternatives don't have to be subtypes, if I am not mistaken. So if you have two different types unrelated to each other but both having that attribute whose value you want to check to decide on the type, that should be possible. As with all questions, provide the minimal but complete details you have.

Comment: I have now edited the complete question. I hope the issue becomes more clear now.
Please let me know if I should ask a completely new question instead because the content of it became much more extended even though the problem still remains similar.

Comment: @DanielJanz, can you provide a minimal but complete schema that doesn't compile and also include details about the software that doesn't compile it?

Comment: Added the software and XML-version I am working with as well as the one missing line of code. I hope my edit is now more complete.

Comment: By the way, your solution finally solved my problem. Thank you so much this really had me blocked for quite a while!